# R - Faster way to run multiple linear models with different design matrices

Tags: r, performance, vectorization, linear-regression

I have a data matrix where every column corresponds to some measured substance concentrations and I need to regress every substance to every other substance, with some fixed correction covariates.
As the design matrix is changing all the time, functions like `fastLm()` from the `RcppArmadillo` package are not substantially useful (I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571282/fit-many-linear-models-in-r-with-identical-design-matrices) before).

The very naive and unadvisable idea is to make a for loop, like

```
Ncol <- ncol(mat)
mat1 <- mat2 <- matrix(ncol=Ncol, nrow=Ncol) ## matrices where I'll save what I need

for(i in seq(Ncol)) {
  for(j in seq(Ncol)[-i]) {
    mylm <- lm(mat[,i] ~ mat[,j] + covariates)
    mat1[i,j] <- summary(mylm)$something
    mat2[i,j] <- summary(mylm)$something.else
  }
}
```

which I am actually currently running, as I had no better ideas. I am not familiar with vectorization algorithms, but I am pretty sure it would kick the speed up a notch.

Does anybody have any suggestion about how to make the computation faster? I have to run the analysis on 4 datasets, with approximately 300, 650, 800, 2000 columns each...

Comment: What are `something` and `something.else` in your case?

Comment: Oh, I left that on purpuose. Actually I need three data: the p-value for `mat[,j]`, R-squared and the number of samples used. Are you thinking of dropping the `lm` part  and calculating those values directly from the data?

Comment: The loop might not be such a bad idea in those circumstances. For speeding up, have you thought of using parrallel computing (using a package such as `doSNOW`, for instance?

Comment: @jeiroje, yes, that is what I am going to try

Comment: @Julius I did not give it much thought, but that could actually be the turning point. I should revise my math a bit ;-)

Comment: @DominicComtois I was just about to try it (I am not familiar with parallel computing either), but I got an error message from the lm() and I am currently trying to solve that one instead. But I will definitely do that as soon as the function works properly.

Comment: I checked and got that working with matrices is much faster than using your loop, but then @Andrey Shabalin's approach is even better, so I am not going to finish mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what my package `MatrixEQTL` does.
Here is a code for running it on your data. 
(Cannot test it without your data, so let me know if something is wrong.)

```
library(MatrixEQTL)
data = SlicedData$new(t(mat))
cvrt = SlicedData$new(t(covariates))
me = Matrix_eQTL_engine(
   snps = data,
   gene = data,
   cvrt = cvrt,
   output_file_name = NULL,
   pvOutputThreshold = 1,
   useModel = modelLINEAR, 
   errorCovariance = numeric(), 
   verbose = TRUE,
   pvalue.hist = FALSE,
   min.pv.by.genesnp = FALSE,
   noFDRsaveMemory = FALSE);
```

The t-statistics and p-values will be in `me$all$eqtls`.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey! I am checking your package right now and will let you know how it works!

Comment: Hi @Andrey, sorry but I had no internet access for some days. I can not say if it worked, as I could not understand the output in `me$all$eqtls`so well. The reference manual was also not so clear either - I do not know if it was just me, but it would be nice to have some more interpretation details on that. To my problem: it turned out a couple of days ago that we will proceed without linear models, so eventually I am not going to need these calculations, but I will keep it in mind if I'll need it again (and if I get to understand the outputs). Thanks anyway!